# Sending Packets Between Computers

Tags: networking, port

I have two computers, A and B. I've successfully sent packets from B to A using `telnet` and `netcat`. When I try going the other way, it doesn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing differently between the two, and I'm not sure how to even diagnose the problem in the first place.

**Example of Correct Behavior**

Computer A:

```bsh
mathgirl277@computer-a:~$ telnet -l serveral 192.168.1.215 443
Trying 192.168.1.215...
Connected to 192.168.1.215.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
I am talking from afar.
^]

telnet> Connection closed.
```

Computer B:

```bsh
serveral@computer-b:~$ sudo nc -lkv 443
[sudo] password for serveral: 
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 443)
Connection from [192.168.1.243] port 443 [tcp/https] accepted (family 2, sport 33704)
hello
I am talking from afar.
Connection closed, listening again.
^C
```

**Example of Incorrect Behavior**

Computer A:

```bsh
mathgirl277@computer-a:~$ sudo nc -lkv 443
[sudo] password for mathgirl277: 
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 443)
```

Computer B:

```bsh
serveral@computer-b:~$ telnet -l mathgirl277 192.168.1.243 443
Trying 192.168.1.243...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

---

I think it's possible that something's up with the NAT configuration, allowing me access in one direction, but not the other. On the other hand, they're both on the same network, and I get the sense that means the NAT shouldn't really be relevant.

What steps should I take to diagnose and solve the problem?

---

Output of `iptables -nvL`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 443 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0            all  --  *      *       192.168.1.215        192.168.1.243       

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Since the hosts are in the same segment, it's most likely a host-based firewall problem on 192.168.1.243. I'd focus my efforts there.

Comment: Okay, I started looking into the iptables firewall after you posted your comment, and played around with several different rules, none of which allowed me to connect from 198.168.1.215 to 198.168.1.243. Further, the server at 192.168.1.215 doesn't have any non-default iptables rules.

Comment: If you do suspect a NAT issue what does your network setup actually look like?

Comment: @MathGirl277 Please post the output of `iptables -nvL` on 192.168.1.243.

Comment: @Seth I only mentioned a NAT because upon searching, people with similar issues had a problem with configuring their NATs. For me, the two computers are connected to the same network via the same router, so I don't think that the NAT has to be configured to account for this case.

Comment: `iptables` output looks good. Probably the next step would be to use tcpdump on the server (192.168.1.243), to see if packets are actually arriving and are being returned. This can tell you if the problem is with the server or with the client.